# SSIS Package error- SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ado, sql-agent-job

SSIS job has failed and posting the below error

> [Product Sales [749]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type float of the specified target column.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Product Sales" (749) failed with error code 0xC020844B while processing input "ADO NET Destination Input" (752). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Can some one please advise if you have come across this kind of error

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add a `data conversion task` between `source` and `destination` to change data type from `string` to `float` , it will resolve your issue .
If still you are facing the issue then let me know the exact issue what are the source and which ssis task you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Your error message is explaining the issue to you: "The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type float of the specified target column."

Open the component that is failing and review the metadata. You have a float column somewhere and you are passing this column a string that can't be converted to a float, such as empty space or an alphanumeric value.

If you want to ensure these values are floats, you can add a script component above the one that is failing and write some code to ensure the value is properly sanitized:

```
string input = "1.1"; //Replace with your input buffer value
float result;
float.TryParse(input, out result); //Result = 0.0 if value was not parsed
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.found that cause as there are null values in the net sales column for the couple of transactions.Hence the reason.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ole db source and destination instead of odc and try to reduce the column name length and no paranthesis in column names and use table and fast load this should solve. I had the same problem where loading from analysis services cube through dax query into SQL Table of my local machine

Comment: this issue has a correct answer and for past 3 years . problem is datatype and this solution is not true. please read help-center : https://stackoverflow.com/help and  give a bronze badge here : https://stackoverflow.com/tour